# Issue print open layer street map

Tags: printing, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have an OpenLayers map that is working fine. I need to print the map with a button in javascript, but when I execute the print() function, the map doesn't show.
I have searched for a solution (GeoEXT, MapFish) but I am new to web mapping and I haven't found a solution. Are there any simple solutions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

GeoEXT provides both a MapFish and Geoserver print module -- note both of these involve setting up a server to do the actual printing, see http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/print-preview-osm.html.

Another option might be phantomJS which is a headless Webkit browser that has a rasterization component, see rasterize.js on http://phantomjs.org/examples/index.html, and allows you to render a page to either png, jpg or pdf, if you want to stay entirely in the javascript world.

You will probably need to give more information about to setup to get more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new page and copy the content of your OpenLayers canvas like so:

```
function printDiv() {
var widthPx = document.getElementById('OpenLayers_canvas').offsetWidth;
var heightPX = document.getElementById('OpenLayers_canvas').offsetHeight;
var html =
    '<html><head>'
    + '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/printing.css" type="text/css" />'
    + '</head><body onload="window.focus();window.print();window.close();">'
    + '<div id="pageFrame">'
    + '<div id="pageTitle">My sample map print</div>'
    + '<div id="OpenLayers_printcanvas">'
    + '<div style="width:' + widthPx + 'px;height:' + heightPX + 'px;left:-'+ ((widthPx/2) - 396) +'px" id="OpenLayers_canvas">'
    + document.getElementById('OpenLayers_canvas').innerHTML
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '</div>'
    + '</body></html>';
var w = window.open();
    w.document.write(html);
    w.document.close();
}
```

I use the page frame to define the desired output format.

This is the content of the printing.css:

```
#pageFrame {
width:816px;
height:1056px;
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
border:1px solid black;
}

#pageTitle {
display:block;
text-align:center;
font-family:'Helvetica Light','Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
padding:10px;
}

#OpenLayers_printcanvas {
display:block;
margin:10px;
border:1px solid black;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:999;
}

#OpenLayers_canvas {
position:relative;
}
```